# Metal on iOS: `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount` not working

Tags: ios, gpu, metal

I have a complex Metal renderer that utilizes numerous `MTLCommandBuffer` objects, and so I've started using `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount` to allow my `MTLCommandQueue` to support more than the default 64 active command buffers, but as far as I can tell, it is not working. **No matter what value I pass in as the `MaxCommandBufferCount`, I am only able to create up to 64 simultaneous command buffers.**

Here is my call to create the command queue:

```
    commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount: 128];
```

And here is the code I use to test this:

```
- (id <MTLCommandBuffer>) makeCommandBuffer
{
    id <MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
    commandBufferCounter ++;
    NSLog(@"command buffer created. Total count = %d", commandBufferCounter);
    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> _Nonnull buffer) {
        commandBufferCounter--;
        NSLog(@"command buffer completed. Total count = %d", commandBufferCounter);
    }];

    return commandBuffer;
}
```

This function is the sole creator of command buffers in my program, and so I can always see an exact count of how many active, non-completed buffers I have. As soon as I hit 64, the call to `[commandQueue commandBuffer]` hangs, which leads me to suspect a bug in `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount`.

I've confirmed this behavior on both iOS 9 and 10, and so I tend to doubt that such an obvious bug would have lasted this long.

Comment: Why would you ever need that many command buffers in flight? Can you consolidate your work into fewer buffers?

Comment: It is due to the way the code is structured, but I've been able to work around this problem by reducing the number, though it makes my code significantly more complex. Still, I felt it was worth mentioning that `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount` seems to be misbehaving. Also, having `[MTLCommandQueue commandBuffer]` just freeze up waiting for a command buffer when none are available isn't a documented behavior, at least nowhere I was able to find.

Comment: It might not be documented as a blocking call, but it is a blocking call, and that's by design.

Comment: @warrenm Got it, makes sense. I will file a documentation bug just to recommend that something be added to describe this behavior. Also, do you agree that `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount` is misbehaving?

Comment: No. There is an upper bound to the number of buffers the driver can keep in flight at once. `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount` can be used to create a queue that holds _fewer_ than that number, but there's no reason to suppose you should be able to create a queue that holds more. Perhaps that should be documented as well.

Comment: Ok @warrenm, I was getting ready to file my documentation bug when I noticed the following paragraph in `[MTLCommandQueue commandBuffer]`: "_If the command queue was instantiated with a maximum number of command buffers and the app already has that many buffers waiting to be executed, then this method blocks until one of those buffers becomes available._". Pretty sure this wasn't there before so looks like that was fixed.

Comment: I did file a bug asking for some clarifications for `newCommandQueueWithMaxCommandBufferCount`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Can you share the Radar number here?

Comment: @warrenm it is 29756828.

Comment: "Why would you ever need that many command buffers in flight?"

I just reversed engineered part of the rendering engine in RealityKit, and they are setting up the command queue with a max buffer count of 1024. Just a funny sidenote, some 6 years later :)